# How to read from a file without trailing new line in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I need to match a pattern which does not have a new line character in it. Target file looks something like:

test

I want to replace test with a content which i get from a file. In notepad++ there is text in one line i.e., there is only "1" in left side of notepad++. I tried the following:

```
PS D:\> $test = get-content tree.txt -raw
PS D:\> $test
test
PS D:\> $test > tree.txt
PS D:\> $test.trim() > tree.txt
PS D:\> $test.trimEnd() > tree.txt
PS D:\> $test.replace("`n","")
test
PS D:\> $test.replace("t","f")
fesf
PS D:\> $test.replace("\n","")
test
PS D:\> $test.replace("`n","") > tree.txt
Set-Content -NoNewline $test tree.txt
```

But it still appends a new-line at the end. The last statement does not append new line but i want the same output in a variable.
The final command looks something like:

```
$file -replace "[\s]+","" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $pattern.trimEnd(),"black-ink-mark"}
```

The $pattern should not contain any newline character.

**Update**: Sample
I need to replace *test* in *tree.txt* file with *black-ink-mark*

```
PS D:\> get-content tree.txt
<element>test</element>
PS D:\> get-content tree2.txt
test
PS D:\> $pattern = get-content tree2.txt -raw
PS D:\> $file = get-content tree.txt -raw
PS D:\> $file -replace "[\s]+","" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace {$pattern.replace('`n','')},"black-ink-mark"}
<element>test</element>
PS D:\>
```

Comment: If you just want to read the 1st line from a file, without a trailing newline, use `$test = Get-Content tree.txt | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: I did `$pattern = Get-Content output.txt | Select-Object -First 1 > tree2.txt` and it still outputs a newline in tree2 file. Updated the question

Comment: `>` invariably adds a newline. Use `Out-File -NoNewline` or `Set-Content -NoNewline`, but note that the output encodings differ in Windows PowerShell, and in other respects the cmdlets only behave the same with string-typed input.

Comment: The problem is not the pattern file, as the contents of that file is coming outside of poweshell i.e., i can delete that extra line (from notepad++). In the above example,  get-content from $pattern (tree2) file appends a new line, even if the original file does not have one. I need to remove that extra line from variable

Comment: `Get-Content -Raw` doesn't append a newline on reading, but you can always trim it on demand. Note that you cannot meaningfully pass a script block (`{...}`) as the first RHS operand to `-replace`. `'\`n'` is a string literal, due to being enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: If you simply replace the last command with `$file.Replace($pattern,"black-ink-mark")` It works fine. you don't need to remove any new line.

Comment: PS. The Newline in Windows is made up of two characters: `CR` and `LF`. In PowerShell that would be `\`r\`n`, not just `\`n`

Answer (score 0):

From @moshe perez.

This works:

```
$file.Replace($pattern,"black-ink-mark")
```